# Show Javascript data-attribute value in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to show data-attribute value inside any tag. But how can I apply if else conditions to show text ?

For example, if there is data-attribute with value, then it will be display. But if there's no data-attribute found, the default text will be display.

Here's my simple code.

```
<h2 id="text" data-text="A Data Text Message"></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
let message = document.getElementById("text").getAttribute("data-text");

/* If data-text attribute found with value, then this message will be show*/
// document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = message;

/* Otherwise this default message will be display*/
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="A Data Text Messages";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let message = document.getElementById("text").getAttribute("data-text");

if (message) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = message;
} else {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="A Data Text Messages";
}
```

```html
<h2 id="text" data-text="A Data Text Message"></h2>
```

You just need to check if the message variable is truthy. If the data-text attribute has a value, it'll be truthy, if it doesn't, it won't be.

Comment: Almost all the given solutions were good. But for me, It's looks easy. Thanks @Adam Pearson

Comment: Thank you for the edit on my question... I keep forgetting that `??` is now standard, ever since IE went out of support life.  However, it's worth noting that `??` is not the same as `?:` as it does not deal with empty strings as falsey

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use the [conditional (ternary) operator `? :`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

If message is null or empty it will use the 2nd part of the operator...

```js
// Example using attribute
setH2(document.getElementById("text"));

// Example using empty or missing attribute
setH2(document.getElementById("text2"));

function setH2(ctrl) {
  let message = ctrl.getAttribute("data-text");
  ctrl.innerHTML = (message ? message : "A Data Text Messages");
}
```

```html
<h2 id="text" data-text="A Data Text Message"></h2>
<h2 id="text2"></h2>
```

You could also simplify this by using the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing):

```js
// Example using attribute
setH2(document.getElementById("text"));

// Example missing attribute
setH2(document.getElementById("text2"));

// Example EMPTY attribute
setH2(document.getElementById("text3"));

function setH2(ctrl) {
  let message = ctrl.getAttribute("data-text");
  ctrl.innerHTML = (message ?? "A Data Text Messages");
}
```

```html
<h2 id="text" data-text="A Data Text Message"></h2>
<h2 id="text2"></h2>
<h2 id="text3" data-text=""></h2>
```

This checks if message is nullish - if it is, it uses whatever is after the ??, if it is not, it uses the message variable.

**BUT NOTE** this it does not recognise the empty attribute as being falsey.. so it will only work with a **missing** attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can apply if-else condition this way:

```
if (message == undefined || message.length == 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="A Data Text Messages";
  }
else{ 
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = message;
  }
```